# Example of a Multi Condition Delete with Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

Can someone give me an example of how I would delete a row in mysql with Zend framework when I have two conditions?

i.e: (trying to do this)

```
"DELETE FROM messages WHERE message_id = 1 AND user_id = 2"
```

My code (that is failing miserably looks like this)

```
// is this our message?
$condition = array(
                   'message_id = ' => $messageId,
                   'profile_id = ' => $userId
);

$n = $db->delete('messages', $condition);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of an associative array, you should just be passing in an array of criteria expressions, ala:

```
$condition = array(
    'message_id = ' . $messageId,
    'profile_id = ' . $userId
);
```

(and make sure you escape those values appropriately if they're coming from user input)

Comment: Will this come out as: "DELETE FROM messages WHERE message_id = 1 AND user_id = 2" or "DELETE FROM messages WHERE (message_id = 1) AND (user_id = 2) ?

Comment: If I read the source correctly, it'll actually put the parentheses around each...  /library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php, _whereExpr (line 564 or so...)

Answer (score 29):

Better to use this:

```
$condition = array(
    'message_id = ?' => $messageId,
    'profile_id = ?' => $userId
);
```

The placeholder symbols (?) get substituted with the values, escapes special characters, and applies quotes around it.

Answer (score -3):

Use this , it is working...

```
$data = array(
    'bannerimage'=>$bannerimage
);

$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', 5);

$table->update($data, $where);
```

Comment: Especially when the answer shows an "update" instead of a "delete".